# Graph chart that have curves and shading in a card

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: graph image]

here I see a curved graph how i can show as a front end developer, i never done something like this, is it html css or javascript or jquery?
how i can conver this layout.

Comment: Graph image is missing and need sample code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScript Sparkline](https://github.com/fnando/sparkline) to generate these charts